# zsh autocomplete menu press enter once

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I'm looking for a zsh option that allows me to only press enter once when the autocompletionmenu in open. The it works now I have to press enter to select an item in the menu and make it go away and then once again to actually execute the command.

Sort of like how vim's wildmenu works.

Is this possible in zsh?

Answer (score 4):

Add this line do your .zshrc:

```
bindkey -M menuselect '^M' .accept-line
```