# zsh: Select menu auto-completion with single Enter/Return press

Tags: zsh, tab-completion

Once finding the auto-completion I want to select from the completions menu, I currently need to hit `<Enter>` twice - once to add the selection to the terminal, and once to execute the command.

Is there a way to press `<Enter>` once to do both?

---

I've also tried

```bsh
bindkey -M menuselect '^M' .accept-line
```

from https://superuser.com/a/817451/1012390,

but I get an error every time I launch a new terminal:

```
/home/kipras/.zshrc:bindkey:32: no such keymap `menuselect'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I was missing this line in [my `~/.zshrc`](https://github.com/sarpik/voidrice/blob/master/.zshrc):

```sh
zmodload -i zsh/complist
```

(should be placed before `bindkey -M menuselect '^M' .accept-line`)

Solved [in this github gist](https://gist.github.com/LukeSmithxyz/e62f26e55ea8b0ed41a65912fbebbe52#gistcomment-3079386) by [github.com/okapia](https://github.com/okapia) <3

---

Full answer:

```
bindkey -M menuselect '^M' .accept-line
```

Move it down to later in your `.zshrc`. The `menuselect` keymap is defined in the complist module. You may have a line which says `zmodload -i zsh/complist` so it needs to be after that. It is also possible that the module is only being loaded by some plugin manager/framework but if you've got the cursor driven completion menu working then it must load at some stage. `zmodload` without arguments lists loaded modules.